# Return a list of Azure Blob Objects returns 403

Tags: azure, blob

[image]
In the CXP i have blobs that i would like to return - not problem when using Postman so fetch the data, but I have trouble return data from a Angular method.
I flollowed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key
It gives me a 403 error:

"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

UPDATE

Will this response bring any light on the issue?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you trim off the authorization key a little bit in your screen shot (for security reasons and stuff)

Comment: can you share a fiddler capture of the request?

Comment: Have you configured the CORS rules?

Comment: @Gaurav - Cors RUles? On Azure?

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav Mantri mentioned that it seems that you need to set the CORS rules on the blob

storage service. By default, CORS is **disabled** for each storage service.

We also could set it from Azure portal. More details please refer to the screenshot.

> Note: CORS is not supported for Premium Storage accounts.

[image]

**Reference**:

[Windows Azure Storage: Introducing CORS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors/)

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Support for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services#understanding-cors-requests)

Comment: Thanks for your response - I did actually have my CORS configured. I it stil a question about the structure and correctness of the request.